# Работа с торрент файлами во flash

Tags: flash, torrent

Если кто пользуется программой uTorrent, вы наверно видели там функцию просмотра видео в потоке, т.е. киношка проигрывается в ихнем плеере прямо в процессе скачивания. Мне вот интересно, возможно ли реализовать похожую вещь только в веб, не скачивая перед сам файл на сервер ? Т.е. чтобы все происходило на стороне клиент, например во flash приложении.

Пытался искать информацию по работе с торрент файлами в флеше, ничего не нашел, постоянно предлагают скачать что-то с торрентов)) Накидайте ссылок по теме, если это вообще возможно конечно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пока во флеше смотреть это не получится. Говоря очень просто: флеш умеет ловить поток только [RTMP](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTMP) или [RTMFP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Media_Flow_Protocol) - это проприетарные протоколы, судя по всему надстроенные над базовым [RTP](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTP). А торрентовое видео вероятнее всего идет в соответствии с протоколом HLS (либо похожим), и флеш его проиграть никак не сумеет.
Хотя говорят, что JWPlayer поддерживает HLS - [посмотрите](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/forums/jw-player/setup-issues-and-embedding/15223/flash-http-streaming-support) сами.